# finding all occurences of date in a string with regex

Tags: regex

I wrote a regex which looks for date (optionally followed by time) in a string.
Here it is:

`(?:[^0-9]+|^)([0-9]{4})[.-]?([0-9]{2})[.-]?([0-9]{2})(?:[_ \-]?([0-9]{2})[\-.;_]?([0-9]{2})[\-.;_]?([0-9]{2}))?(?:[^0-9]+|$)`

The elements which are causing me problems are `(?:[^0-9]+|^)` (first non capturing group) and `(?:[^0-9]+|$)` (last non capturing group). I need them to for cases like: `12020-08-02` (not a date) or `2020-08-022` (not a date either).
But when I input `2020-08-02/2020-08-03` I'd expect two matches, yet I get only one, because `/` becomes part of first match and as regex cannot find `(?:[^0-9]+|^)` in remaining input and drops rest of it.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/oKMUMl/1) you can see more samples for my regex with long input. As you can see there some occurrences of `2020-07-21` were not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression looks kinda complicated. Not sure if I grasped all your requirements, but this seems to work with all your examples:

```
(?<=\D|^)[0-9]{4}[\.-][0-9]{2}[\.-][0-9]{2}(?=\D)(_[0-9]{2}[\:\.-][0-9]{2}[:\.-][0-9]{2})?
```

- Dates are recognized with `.` and `-` as separator (lookbehind/lookahead to exclude trailing digits)
- Time is recognized optionally after a `_` with `.`, `-` and `:` as separators (was it time you intended to detect?)

Edit: now I realized you probably just meant to use lookbehind and lookahead instead of non capturing groups:

```
(?<=[^0-9]|^)([0-9]{4})[.-]?([0-9]{2})[.-]?([0-9]{2})(?:[_ \-]?([0-9]{2})[\-.;_]?([0-9]{2})[\-.;_]?([0-9]{2}))?(?=[^0-9]+|$)
```

Comment: Yes it seems so! I didn't know this feature :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pattern like `(?:[^0-9]+|^)` or `(?:[^0-9]+|$)` actually consumes this part `[^0-9]+` not making it able to become part of the next match.

Note that you don't have to escape the `-` in the character class.

What you might do is use word boundaries instead `\b` as the dates should start and end with an exact amount of digits, not followed by a digit.

You can omit the capture groups if you don't need them for after processing.

```
\b[0-9]{4}[.-]?[0-9]{2}[.-]?[0-9]{2}(?:[_ -]?[0-9]{2}[-.;_]?[0-9]{2}[-.;_]?[0-9]{2})?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zxszg4/1)

If you want to match up the delimiters (`2010.10-11` will not be matched in this case) you can use 2 capture groups with 2 backreferences

```
\b[0-9]{4}([.-]?)[0-9]{2}\1[0-9]{2}(?:[_ -]?[0-9]{2}([-.;_]?)[0-9]{2}\2[0-9]{2})?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G40w2A/1)